# for loop not executing some codes

Tags: objective-c

```
for (int i = 0; i < [menuArray count]; i++) {

        [menuItem addObject:menuArray[i][@"Description"]];
        keywordArray = (NSMutableArray *)[menuItem[i] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

}
```

I am trying to break up the strings in the menuItem array, which has 370 objects. However, keywordArray is only taking the first item of menuItem. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: You will need to show us the contents of `menuArray`.  Otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: `componentsSeperatedByString` outputs an `NSArray *`, you can't just cast it to be mutable, you need to acquire a mutable copy by messaging `mutableCopy` to it. Also, you're overwriting `keywordArray` in each iteration of your loop.

Comment: @Leandros can you show me the code for that please?

Comment: `[[menuItem[i] componentsSeperatedByString:@" "] mutableCopy]`

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to work out what you are doing here...

```
for (int i = 0; i < [menuArray count]; i++) {
    [menuItem addObject:menuArray[i][@"Description"]];
    keywordArray = (NSMutableArray *)[menuItem[i] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
}
```

It looks like you're trying to put stuff into the `keywordArray` from the `menuArray`. I'm not really sure what the `menuItem` array is?!

Anyway, your like of code `keywordArray = (NSMutableArray *)[menuItem[i] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];` will not add stuff to `keywordArray` it will create a whole new array every time.

If you want to build up the keywordArray then you need to do something like this.

```
NSMutableArray *keywordArray = [NSMutableArray array];

for (blah...) {
    //... do stuff ...
    [keywordArray addObjectsFromArray:[menuItem[i] componentsSeparatedByString:@" "]];
}
```

I'm only guessing though as you've put pretty much no information in your question. If this isn't right then please update your question to explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: @coder1234 glad I could help. Remember to up vote and accept the answer if it helped :-)